# create multiple instances of a class without array in a loop

Tags: java, class, loops, object

I know this question been asked many times, and I've looked through many similar topics but they all include array or list and I don't want to use array or lists, second I don't understand :). 
Anyway here's my question: I have a class with name,id,job methods to store these in a variable, and I want to to ask how many Staff the company has, and that's why I cant hard code each variable because the number is unknown thus I need a loop, And am not allowed to use array or list. Any idea or help is appreciated Thanks.

Here's the code for the class:

```
public class Staff{
    public void name(String name){
        String staff_name = name;
    }
    public void id(String id){
        String staf_id = id;
    }
    public void job(String job){
        String staff_job = job;
    }
}
```

code for main:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class P2Q2{
    public static void main(String[]args){

        System.out.println("How many staff in Department? ");
        String staff_num = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"How many Staff are there",
                "Department staff numbers",JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
        int staff_num_int = Integer.parseInt(staff_num);

        for(int i=1;i<staff_num_int;i++){
            //somthing in here to create objects for each staff
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the whole question:

[image]

EDIT:
I just didn't want to provide the whole question, but if this is better there you go.

Comment: Why are you not allowed to use array or list?

Comment: ask the lecturer :/  , and why -1 :(

Comment: You can have a static count variable in the Staff class that tells you how many times an instance has been created, if that's what you're meaning. I am having a hard time understanding what you really want, to be honest.

Comment: i thought i explained clearly, i want to create object with different references for each Staff !!!

Comment: create a constructor for staff and assign values inside it to your instance variables. And call the constructor for each staff_num. If that is what you are looking for.

Comment: Oh, you mean `Staff s1 = new Staff();`? Usually you would initialize the fields in the constructor, but since you don't have any, simply do `s1.name("John")`, etc.

Comment: Iit is meaningless to create multiple instances of a class, in a loop, without storing references to them somewhere.  The only options for doing so are a Collection of some kind or an array.  If you don't store the references, you will not be able to use the instances later in your program, and the garbage collector will remove them.  This question is not answerable.

Comment: Perhaps the lecturer is fine with the objects being unreachable. Perhaps the objects are not metaphors for humans, but mayflies, which have an incredibly short lifespan.

Comment: i see thanks everyone :/

Comment: @JimGarrison will you have a look at the image :)

Comment: @AbdulAziz That doesn't help at all. Most of the image is blank. I've edited it into the question.

Comment: @JimGarrison How about now, sorry I just want to solve that part as i don't want you guys to solve my assignment for me :D, any ideas are welcomed

Answer (score 0):

You can create `Staff` objects without array or list - but it will not have sense because you will not have access to the objects. If you will not have access to the objects - that means the Garbage Collector will destroy them after you go out the loop scope.

Comment: Wrong. You can create a separate variable for each instance.

Comment: I know and thats not what i want, because later on i want to access these objects and add salary and stuff

Comment: @Gendarme ok, maybe I am wrong. Can you explain it?

Comment: You can have references to objects without putting them in arrays or lists. `Staff s = new Staff();` is not in an array or list, but it is perfectly fine.

Comment: This is at best a comment. The question is not answerable.

Comment: @Gendarme so what happens if we go out the loop? How to access first or fifth Staff variable?

Comment: I misunderstood what you were saying originally. I didn't notice that you were talking about inside the loop. Of course, the loop has to go. My bad.

Answer (score 0):

Well if you can't use an array or list, and you want to access to each staff object. You can look into using something such as a hash map. You can store objects in the hash map and just use the staff names as a key to access each object after created and added to the map.